# Catalan number calculation using Python?

Tags: python, catalan

I am writing a Python code to generate Catalan numbers using the mathematical formula given here:

C(0) = 1 and C(n) = (2(2n − 1) / (n + 1)) * C(n − 1) per this website here. (https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Catalan_numbers)

However, when I am writing it in python as a function, it gives me false results.

eg: For 20 answer should be 6564120420.0 while my code gives me 344373768.

Here:

```
def catalan(cat_input):

    if cat_input==0:
    return 1 

    else:
    return  (((4*cat_input) - 2) / (cat_input + 1)) * (catalan(cat_input-1))
```

Can someone help me figure this out please ?

Comment: Whay do you mean by "false results" give an example (as far as i have tested it the program gives correct results at least up to 9) -- well except the results being floats instead of ints which can be fixed by using `//` instead of `/`

Comment: Made the change in the asked question to answers yours.

Comment: For me, using the above code, catalan(20) is 6564120420.0

Comment: works as expected. btw your indents are messed up.

Comment: Because you guys use python3 and not python2, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when dividing `/`. As-is the result (of the division itself, before multiplying) may not be whole number, and since `/` in python2 is by default int-division the decimal part gets "cropped" and you get the wrong results.

There are couple ways to fix that (pick your favorite):

- Change the order in the equation, instead of `(((4*cat_input) - 2) / (cat_input + 1)) * (catalan(cat_input-1))` use `(((4*cat_input) - 2) * (catalan(cat_input-1)) / (cat_input + 1))`, that way you are guaranteed to get whole number after division
- change the type of the first part of the equation to `float` to force float division: `(float((4*cat_input) - 2) / (cat_input + 1)) * (catalan(cat_input-1))`
- Use python3 instead of python2 as python3 uses decimal division by default
- Use `from __future__ import division` to "activate" python3-like division

Edit: In general (at least in python) it is advised not to use recursion if possible, as it is not efficient and you may run to problems like recursion limit